# gRPC in CPP providing TLS support

Tags: c++, grpc

Any examples of gRPC server using TLS in CPP??

I am trying to build a gRPC application. The server should provide TLS support if client wants to connect over TLS instead of TCP.

This is my server

```
void RunServer() {
    std::string server_address("0.0.0.0:50051");
    GreeterServiceImpl service;
    ServerBuilder builder;
    std::shared_ptr<ServerCredentials> creds;

    if(enable_ssl)
    {
            grpc::SslServerCredentialsOptions::PemKeyCertPair pkcp ={"a","b"};
            grpc::SslServerCredentialsOptions ssl_opts;
            ssl_opts.pem_root_certs="";
            ssl_opts.pem_key_cert_pairs.push_back(pkcp);
            creds = grpc::SslServerCredentials(ssl_opts);
    }
    else
            creds=grpc::InsecureServerCredentials();
    // Listen on the given address without any authentication mechanism.
    builder.AddListeningPort(server_address, creds);
    // Register "service" as the instance through which we'll communicate with
    // clients. In this case it corresponds to an *synchronous* service.
    builder.RegisterService(&service);
    // Finally assemble the server.
    std::unique_ptr<Server> server(builder.BuildAndStart());
```

Error:
undefined reference to grpc::SslServerCredetials(grpc::ssl_opts)
I have included all the necessary files..

Comment: He likely meant the the encryption thing not thread local storage.

Comment: ya! not about the thread library but about the way TLS can be used.

Answer (score 2):

You code looks right. If you are adapting from `examples/cpp/helloworld`, you need to change `-lgrpc++_unsecure` to `-lgrpc++` in the Makefile.

For the benefits of others, an example of using the tls/ssl code can be found at https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/test/cpp/interop/server_helper.cc#L50

Comment: lib/libgrpc.so.0.11.0.0: undefined reference to `EVP_DigestVerifyInit'
lib/libgrpc.so.0.11.0.0: undefined reference to `SSL_get0_next_proto_negotiated'
/lib/libgrpc.so.0.11.0.0: undefined reference to `SSL_get_servername'
lib/libgrpc.so.0.11.0.0: undefined reference to `SSL_set_SSL_CTX'
lib/libgrpc.so.0.11.0.0: undefined reference to `EVP_DigestVerifyFinal'
Etc.. Getting these undefined references, have no idea why.